# Как сделать активными только определенные дни недели в DatePicker

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, calendar

Я получаю порядковые номера определенных дней недели из базы данных и эти дни должны оставаться активными в DatePicker, а все остальные - нет. Но в итоге получается так, что все дни в календаре неактивны, кроме последнего (у меня это последний день года). Что я делаю не так? За основу брала код по ссылке: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213801/how-to-black-out-specific-days-of-the-week-datepicker-vb (он работает).

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
    var minDate = DateTime.Now;
    var maxDate =new DateTime(year, 12, 31);
    string r;
    string st = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string sql3 = "select distinct id_week from timetable,masters where 
    timetable.id_mas=masters.cod and masters.fio = '" + st + "'";
    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sql3, conn))
    {
        OracleDataReader reader3 = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader3.Read())
        {
            r = reader3[0].ToString();

            for (var d = minDate; d <= maxDate> d; d = d.AddDays(1))
            {
                if ((int)d.DayOfWeek != Convert.ToInt32(r))
                {
                    dateTimePicker1.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(d));
                }
            }
        }

        reader3.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64742931

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в алгоритме, которым вы оперируете. Попробуйте мысленно пройтись по выполняемому коду, представив, что у вас в базе два значения: а) для понедельника и б) для вторника.

Соответственно, у вас при проходе в while в первый раз находится понедельник.

Внутри while в цикле for вы удаляете все дни, кроме понедельника. Окей, пусть так.

Второй проход while идёт по вторнику. Внутри while вы снова входите в for, в котором удаляете все дни, кроме вторника. Но ведь там оставались только понедельники, верно? Значит, вы просто удаляете все оставшиеся дни.

Такой алгоритм будет выглядеть рабочим только если в базе у вас зашит один день недели.

Как сделать алгоритм рабочим? Ну, как вариант - я бы сначала прочитал все дни недели из базы в массив дней недели - а потом проверял бы, что текущий день из цикла for находится в этом массиве.

Ну вот как-то вот так:

```
var days = new[] {1, 2};

var minDate = DateTime.Now;
var maxDate = new DateTime(2020, 12, 31);
for (var d = minDate; d <= maxDate; d = d.AddDays(1))
{
    if (days.Any(x => x == (int)d.DayOfWeek))
    {
        d.Dump();
    }
}
```

Вывод для оставшихся дней в 2020 году:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(инвертируйте условие в if для получения дней которые нужно убрать из календаря)

А вот так могла выглядеть чисто linq-версия этого же кода:

```
var startDate = DateTime.Today;
var finishDate = new DateTime(2020, 12, 31);
var dateDiff = finishDate - startDate;

var daysOfWeek = new[] { 1, 2 };

var result = Enumerable.Range(1, dateDiff.Days)
                       .Select(x => startDate.AddDays(x))
                       .Where(x => daysOfWeek.Any(y => y == (int)x.DayOfWeek))
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: @Ana7 Я думаю, что у вас какой-то другой код выполняется (если что: тот код, что в задании даже не скомпилируется, посмотрите на условие выхода из for внимательно), поэтому до последнего дня даже и не доходит. Типа, на один день меньше в цикле обсчёт идёт. Ну и -- просто этот день не заносится в список исключаемых :) Но это неточно.

Comment: я, как Вы и посоветовали, получаю дни из базы в массив и цикл по этому массиву - всё работает правильно, но вот этот последний день (31 декабря) всегда активен. Получилось его сделать неактивным только отдельно вне цикла. А цикл его как будто игнорирует.

Comment: @Ana7 Звучит, будто вы в коде написали `for (var d = minDate; d < maxDate; d = d.AddDays(1))` вместо `for (var d = minDate; d <= maxDate; d = d.AddDays(1))`. Вы умеете делать брейкпойнты и условные брейкпойнты? Посмотрите в первую очередь то, что у вас вообще входит в цикл for с 31 декабря.